# Gerrit Watched Projects - select specific projects

Tags: gerrit

I want to recive to email notification.

Gerrit has many project. But project name has pattern.

```
Ex)
AAA/abc
AAA/bcd 
AAA/efg
BBB/abc
BBB/bcd 
BBB/efg
CCC/abc
CCC/bcd 
CCC/efg
```

I want to revice email of AAA/abc, AAA/bdc, AAA/efg.

How can I recevie email?

```
Project Name -  AAA/*
Only If      - status:merged
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Project Name - All-Projects
Only If      - projects:AAA branch:master

It is work.

[image]